# Error when extracting a substring in python

Tags: python, split, substring, python-3.5

I have a dataframe, that looks like this:

```
 varA                   json_data
 'string1'      {"str":{"str":"string","str":12345,"str":"str","str":"str","xyz":"1234","zyx":"string1","str":[{"str":"str","str":"str"}],"str":["str","str"],"str":["str"]},"str":"str"}

 'string2'      {"str":{"str":"string","str":12345,"str":"str","str":"str","xyz":"4567","zyx":"string2","str":[{"str":"str","str":"str"}],"str":["str","str"],"str":["str"]},"str":"str"}

 'string3'      {"str":{"str":"string","str":12345,"str":"str","str":"str","xyz":"8910","zyx":"string3","str":[{"str":"str","str":"str"}],"str":["str","str"],"str":["str"]},"str":"str"}
```

I need to create new columns, and populated extracted digits from json_data into the first one, and "string1","string2" and "string3" values to the second new column. The resulted dataset would look like this:

```
   varA        json_data    xyz   zyx
 'string'        ...       1234  string1
 'string'        ...       4567  string2
 'string'        ...       8910  string3
```

The code I have is below:

```
df['xyz'] = df['json_data'].str.split('xyz":')[1].split('","zyx')[0]
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How do I fix it? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Stop trying to split a list.

Comment: `{"string4","string5","xyz":"1234","zyx":"string10"}` is not a legal Python expression: it is neither a set nor a dictionary. Please post the actual dataframe.

Comment: And why wouldn't you treat JSON as JSON, rather than manipulating it as a string?

Comment: The value of the column is a json file, stored as a string type.

Comment: In that case, consider `import json` then `json.loads`.

Comment: @shadow, it is important that I have varA column, along with xyz and zyx columns. varA values are not part of json.

Comment: String `'{"string4","string5","xyz":"1234","zyx":"string10"}'` is not legal JSON, either. Attempt to parse it causes an error.

Comment: @FeyziBagirov The code you've posted has some obvious errors unrelated to the issue you're seeing (as does the data). It's hard for people to help you as a result. Please copy/paste the code & data you're testing against to prevent this issue

Comment: Meanwhile, `df['json_data'].str.split('"xyz":"').str[1].str.split('","zyx"').str[0]` is the corrected version of your faulty statement, but it does not seem to be the right way to solve your big problem.

Comment: @DYZ, that worked! The json column comes in this format, there is nothing I can do to fix it. Thanks!